# Rails server on Mac crashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Background: I had rails working back when Mavericks was on the system. I have since updated to Yosemite so I assume something was broken. It now crashes. But I'm a ruby/rails n00b so...?

EDIT: 2 things... one of the replies to my topic here, although unsuccessful, was deleted?

Second: Would love to get rails running on the MAC but I'm lost. Is there a way to just completely start over? I assume the Yosemite upgrade broke it and I've googled and tried a variety of suggestions for hours now with no success. Would love to be able to just wipe it clean and start over (not the mac, rails).

> Diag log: Process:               ruby [67555] Path:
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
> Identifier:            ruby Version:               106 Code Type:
> X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:        bash [2259] Responsible:
> Terminal [2255] User ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2015-02-22 09:34:54.486 -0500 OS Version:
> Mac OS X 10.10.2 (14C109) Report Version:        11 Anonymous UUID:
> B83A85D8-89E7-B44F-1F87-9D428C3AC62A
>
> Sleep/Wake UUID:       4FC3862A-8C3F-4C10-9407-4115E07EB63B
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 7200 seconds Time Since Wake:       2100
> seconds
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
> KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000418
>
> ### VM Regions Near 0x418:
>
> ```
> __TEXT                 00000001044c6000-00000001044c7000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW
> ```
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
>
> Application Specific Information: abort() called
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
> libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff94610286 __pthread_kill + 10
> 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff86c00b53 abort + 129 2
> libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044f60a1 rb_bug + 185 3
> libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x000000010459ce19 Init_signal + 2961 4
> libsystem_platform.dylib          0x00007fff8a50ff1a _sigtramp + 26 5
> ???                               000000000000000000 0 + 0 6
> libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x0000000104d2ae60 st_init_strcasetable
>
> - 16 (st.c:247) 7   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x0000000104c1cf8e rb_enc_init + 110 (encoding.c:537) 8   libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x0000000104c1e055 rb_usascii_encoding + 21 (encoding.c:1186) 9
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x0000000104cc06da rb_intern2 + 26
>   (parse.y:10402) 10  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x0000000104c3c92f
>   rb_define_module + 15 (class.c:626) 11  nokogiri.bundle
>   0x00000001049c3b48 Init_nokogiri + 56 (nokogiri.c:82) 12
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044cc70f dln_load + 219 13
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3f5a rb_vm_call_cfunc +
>   438 14  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fed24
>   rb_require_safe + 1786 15  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fb376 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 22929 16  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fad55 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 21360 17  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045e8577 rb_vm_get_insns_address_table + 11255 18
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3062 rb_iseq_eval + 524
>   19  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f2fc4 rb_iseq_eval +
>   366 20  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fe4fc rb_load +
>   398 21  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fec80
>   rb_require_safe + 1622 22  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fb376 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 22929 23  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fad55 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 21360 24  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045e8577 rb_vm_get_insns_address_table + 11255 25
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3062 rb_iseq_eval + 524
>   26  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f2fc4 rb_iseq_eval +
>   366 27  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fe4fc rb_load +
>   398 28  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fec80
>   rb_require_safe + 1622 29  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fb376 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 22929 30  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fad55 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 21360 31  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045e8577 rb_vm_get_insns_address_table + 11255 32
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3062 rb_iseq_eval + 524
>   33  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f2fc4 rb_iseq_eval +
>   366 34  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fe4fc rb_load +
>   398 35  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fec80
>   rb_require_safe + 1622 36  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fb376 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 22929 37  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fad55 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 21360 38  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045e8577 rb_vm_get_insns_address_table + 11255 39
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3062 rb_iseq_eval + 524
>   40  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f2fc4 rb_iseq_eval +
>   366 41  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fe4fc rb_load +
>   398 42  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fec80
>   rb_require_safe + 1622 43  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001044fc056 rb_protect + 232 44  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045d1025 rb_autoload_load + 193 45  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fa0a7 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 18114 46  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045e60eb rb_vm_get_insns_address_table + 1899 47
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3062 rb_iseq_eval + 524
>   48  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f2fc4 rb_iseq_eval +
>   366 49  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fe4fc rb_load +
>   398 50  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fec80
>   rb_require_safe + 1622 51  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001044fc056 rb_protect + 232 52  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045d1025 rb_autoload_load + 193 53  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fa0a7 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 18114 54  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045e60eb rb_vm_get_insns_address_table + 1899 55
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3062 rb_iseq_eval + 524
>   56  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f2fc4 rb_iseq_eval +
>   366 57  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fe4fc rb_load +
>   398 58  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fec80
>   rb_require_safe + 1622 59  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fb376 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 22929 60  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fad55 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 21360 61  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045e8577 rb_vm_get_insns_address_table + 11255 62
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3062 rb_iseq_eval + 524
>   63  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f2fc4 rb_iseq_eval +
>   366 64  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fe4fc rb_load +
>   398 65  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fec80
>   rb_require_safe + 1622 66  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001044fc056 rb_protect + 232 67  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045d1025 rb_autoload_load + 193 68  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fa0a7 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 18114 69  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045e60eb rb_vm_get_insns_address_table + 1899 70
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3062 rb_iseq_eval + 524
>   71  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f2fc4 rb_iseq_eval +
>   366 72  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fe4fc rb_load +
>   398 73  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fec80
>   rb_require_safe + 1622 74  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001044fc056 rb_protect + 232 75  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045d1025 rb_autoload_load + 193 76  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045d13d1 rb_const_get_from + 267 77  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fa0ff rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 18202 78  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045e60eb rb_vm_get_insns_address_table + 1899 79
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3062 rb_iseq_eval + 524
>   80  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f2fc4 rb_iseq_eval +
>   366 81  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fe4fc rb_load +
>   398 82  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fec80
>   rb_require_safe + 1622 83  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fb376 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 22929 84  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fad55 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 21360 85  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045e8577 rb_vm_get_insns_address_table + 11255 86
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3062 rb_iseq_eval + 524
>   87  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f2fc4 rb_iseq_eval +
>   366 88  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fe4fc rb_load +
>   398 89  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fec80
>   rb_require_safe + 1622 90  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fb376 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 22929 91  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fad55 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 21360 92  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045e8577 rb_vm_get_insns_address_table + 11255 93
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3062 rb_iseq_eval + 524
>   94  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f086d rb_yield + 216
>   95  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044d138f rb_ary_each + 72
>   96  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045fb376
>   rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 22929 97  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fad55 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 21360 98  libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045e84c9 rb_vm_get_insns_address_table + 11081 99
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3062 rb_iseq_eval + 524
>   100 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f2fc4 rb_iseq_eval +
>   366 101 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fe4fc rb_load +
>   398 102 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fec80
>   rb_require_safe + 1622 103 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fb376 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 22929 104 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fad55 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 21360 105 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045e8577 rb_vm_get_insns_address_table + 11255 106
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3062 rb_iseq_eval + 524
>   107 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f2fc4 rb_iseq_eval +
>   366 108 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fe4fc rb_load +
>   398 109 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fec80
>   rb_require_safe + 1622 110 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fb376 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 22929 111 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fad55 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 21360 112 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045e8577 rb_vm_get_insns_address_table + 11255 113
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3062 rb_iseq_eval + 524
>   114 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f086d rb_yield + 216
>   115 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x000000010453b61e rb_obj_tap + 14
>   116 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045fb376
>   rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 22929 117 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fad55 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 21360 118 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045e84c9 rb_vm_get_insns_address_table + 11081 119
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3062 rb_iseq_eval + 524
>   120 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f2fc4 rb_iseq_eval +
>   366 121 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fe4fc rb_load +
>   398 122 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fec80
>   rb_require_safe + 1622 123 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fb376 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 22929 124 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fad55 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 21360 125 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045e8577 rb_vm_get_insns_address_table + 11255 126
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3062 rb_iseq_eval + 524
>   127 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f2fc4 rb_iseq_eval +
>   366 128 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fe4fc rb_load +
>   398 129 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044ff36d Init_load +
>   681 130 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045fb376
>   rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 22929 131 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fad55 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 21360 132 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045e8577 rb_vm_get_insns_address_table + 11255 133
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3062 rb_iseq_eval + 524
>   134 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f2fc4 rb_iseq_eval +
>   366 135 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fe4fc rb_load +
>   398 136 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044ff36d Init_load +
>   681 137 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045fb376
>   rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 22929 138 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fad55 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 21360 139 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045e8577 rb_vm_get_insns_address_table + 11255 140
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3062 rb_iseq_eval + 524
>   141 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f2fc4 rb_iseq_eval +
>   366 142 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fe4fc rb_load +
>   398 143 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fec80
>   rb_require_safe + 1622 144 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fb376 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 22929 145 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fad55 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 21360 146 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045e8577 rb_vm_get_insns_address_table + 11255 147
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3062 rb_iseq_eval + 524
>   148 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f2fc4 rb_iseq_eval +
>   366 149 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044fe4fc rb_load +
>   398 150 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001044ff36d Init_load +
>   681 151 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045fb376
>   rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 22929 152 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045fad55 rb_ruby_debug_ptr + 21360 153 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001045e8577 rb_vm_get_insns_address_table + 11255 154
>   libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3062 rb_iseq_eval + 524
>   155 libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001045f3be2
>   rb_iseq_eval_main + 138 156 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001044fb3fc ruby_exec_node + 164 157 libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   0x00000001044fb34d ruby_run_node + 78 158 ruby
>   0x00000001044c6e5a main + 91 159 libdyld.dylib
>   0x00007fff89d095c9 start + 1
>
> Thread 1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff946115c2 poll +
> 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fff947dd268 _pthread_body
>
> - 131 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff947dd1e5 _pthread_start + 176 3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff947db41d thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):   rax:
> 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x00007ff4fc0d1318
> rdx: 0x0000000000000000   rdi: 0x0000000000000c0f  rsi:
> 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007ff4fc0d1340  rsp: 0x00007ff4fc0d1318
> r8: 0x00007ff4fc0d11a0   r9: 0x00007fff78a64300  r10:
> 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206   r12: 0x0000000000000008
> r13: 0x00007ff4fb600410  r14: 0x00007fff78a64300  r15:
> 0x00007fff5b72e880   rip: 0x00007fff94610286  rfl: 0x0000000000000206
> cr2: 0x00007fff768a9fd8    Logical CPU:     0 Error Code:
> 0x02000148 Trap Number:     133
>
> Binary Images:
> 0x1044c6000 -        0x1044c6fff  ruby (106) <41FB3071-DF65-36C9-A149-47B66FBE7CE6>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
> 0x1044cb000 -        0x104677ff7  libruby.2.0.0.dylib (106) <02E09C37-483F-37BC-87DA-2347D619FAF9>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/libruby.2.0.0.dylib
> 0x1047fb000 -        0x1047fcfff  encdb.bundle (106) <390E914C-32AA-3B46-BD0B-7432A7B907EA>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/enc/encdb.bundle
> 0x104801000 -        0x104802fff  transdb.bundle (106) 
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
> 0x104828000 -        0x104829fff  etc.bundle (106) <1595D964-5E46-39BF-9539-C25D353824F6>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/etc.bundle
> 0x10482e000 -        0x104831fff  pathname.bundle (106) 
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/pathname.bundle
> 0x104837000 -        0x10483afff  stringio.bundle (106) <1126F7B3-4266-313F-BA22-8CB754D334A2>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/stringio.bundle
> 0x104840000 -        0x104840fff  md5.bundle (106) <83E2D75A-65CF-31F3-9E35-9F494EB65061>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/digest/md5.bundle
> 0x104845000 -        0x104846fff  digest.bundle (106) 
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/digest.bundle
> 0x10484b000 -        0x10484ffff  fiddle.bundle (106) 
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/fiddle.bundle
> 0x104856000 -        0x10486ffff  socket.bundle (106) <7AFD34F7-0F81-38A4-8BEB-1AFD70DD2DFF>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/socket.bundle
> 0x104878000 -        0x104878fff  sha1.bundle (106) <90A37E89-10C4-3419-AEE1-2FED01C45000>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/digest/sha1.bundle
> 0x10487d000 -        0x10487dfff  fcntl.bundle (106) <752D5140-6CBE-375B-A6B8-DFC6F9C2544A>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/fcntl.bundle
> 0x104882000 -        0x1048b1ff7  openssl.bundle (106) 
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/openssl.bundle
> 0x1048c8000 -        0x1048feff7  libssl.0.9.8.dylib (52.10.1) <4A2D6ECA-A07E-38B5-98D4-315A4A1E8CE6> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
> 0x104914000 -        0x104916fff  strscan.bundle (106) 
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/strscan.bundle
> 0x10491c000 -        0x10494fff7  date_core.bundle (106) <761BEA4D-A449-3F4D-AE5E-AF2A67A86E62>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/date_core.bundle
> 0x104958000 -        0x104963ff7  bigdecimal.bundle (106) 
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/bigdecimal.bundle
> 0x104969000 -        0x10496cfff +parser.bundle (0) <684B9702-DDEE-3F4A-9A19-CFF93FD3202A> /Users/USER/*/parser.bundle
> 0x104971000 -        0x104971fff  utf_16be.bundle (106) <40661CA8-E8CD-32FD-8D4F-DF9C5EFE2DEA>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/enc/utf_16be.bundle
> 0x104976000 -        0x104976fff  utf_16le.bundle (106) 
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/enc/utf_16le.bundle
> 0x10497b000 -        0x10497bfff  utf_32be.bundle (106) 
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/enc/utf_32be.bundle
> 0x104980000 -        0x104980fff  utf_32le.bundle (106) 
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/enc/utf_32le.bundle
> 0x104985000 -        0x104989fff +generator.bundle (0) <7997480F-93E0-3C3A-B620-F51629147113> /Users/USER/*/generator.bundle
> 0x104990000 -        0x1049adff7  psych.bundle (106) <22C4114F-9DE3-33D8-85E5-0E5CC73D7B0B>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/psych.bundle
> 0x1049b4000 -        0x1049bbff7  zlib.bundle (106) <4CA5CB02-A6D1-3A9C-8C33-2CF82C32E2CA>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/zlib.bundle
> 0x1049c2000 -        0x104bcffff +nokogiri.bundle (0) <5F9CF871-EC1D-3332-939B-BFA6AA814575> /Users/USER/*/nokogiri.bundle
> 0x104c1a000 -        0x104e1cff7 +libruby.2.0.0.dylib (0) <1345AB45-8C56-3E8A-8BF0-C3FD6FC9A4D9>
> /Users/USER/*/libruby.2.0.0.dylib
> 0x7fff658ba000 -     0x7fff658f0837  dyld (353.2.1) <65DCCB06-339C-3E25-9702-600A28291D0E> /usr/lib/dyld
> 0x7fff8692c000 -     0x7fff86b2646f  libobjc.A.dylib (647) <759E155D-BC42-3D4E-869B-6F57D477177C> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
> 0x7fff86ba3000 -     0x7fff86c2fff7  libsystem_c.dylib (1044.10.1) <199ED5EB-77A1-3D43-AA51-81779CE0A742>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
> 0x7fff86f4c000 -     0x7fff86f54fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (561.1.1) <62B70ECA-E40D-3C63-896E-7F00EC386DDB>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
> 0x7fff876a7000 -     0x7fff876c1ff7  liblzma.5.dylib (7) <1D03E875-A7C0-3028-814C-3C27F7B7C079> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
> 0x7fff87ab2000 -     0x7fff87ab4ff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (358.1.1) <95312E09-DA28-324A-A084-F3E574D0210E>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
> 0x7fff87bcf000 -     0x7fff87cc1ff7  libiconv.2.dylib (42) <2A06D02F-8B76-3864-8D96-64EF5B40BC6C> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
> 0x7fff8824d000 -     0x7fff88252ff7  libmacho.dylib (862) <126CA2ED-DE91-308F-8881-B9DAEC3C63B6> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
> 0x7fff883f2000 -     0x7fff883f2ff7  libkeymgr.dylib (28) <77845842-DE70-3CC5-BD01-C3D14227CED5> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
> 0x7fff88ba3000 -     0x7fff88ba7fff  libcache.dylib (69) <45E9A2E7-99C4-36B2-BEE3-0C4E11614AD1> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
> 0x7fff88bc5000 -     0x7fff88bc6fff  libSystem.B.dylib (1213) <90B107BC-FF74-32CC-B1CF-4E02F544D957> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
> 0x7fff88e38000 -     0x7fff88e3dff7  libsystem_stats.dylib (163.10.18) <9B8CCF24-DDDB-399A-9237-4BEC225D2E8C>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
> 0x7fff89d06000 -     0x7fff89d09ff7  libdyld.dylib (353.2.1) <4E33E416-F1D8-3598-B8CC-6863E2ECD0E6> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
> 0x7fff89d6f000 -     0x7fff89d99ff7  libdispatch.dylib (442.1.4) <502CF32B-669B-3709-8862-08188225E4F0>
> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
> 0x7fff8a386000 -     0x7fff8a39cff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (267) 
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
> 0x7fff8a475000 -     0x7fff8a476fff  libffi.dylib (18.1) <0F6C6A4D-1210-3585-8DA1-B8A94B9924A5> /usr/lib/libffi.dylib
> 0x7fff8a4a5000 -     0x7fff8a4f9fff  libc++.1.dylib (120) <1B9530FD-989B-3174-BB1C-BDC159501710> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
> 0x7fff8a50b000 -     0x7fff8a513fff  libsystem_platform.dylib (63) <64E34079-D712-3D66-9CE2-418624A5C040>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
> 0x7fff8a525000 -     0x7fff8a52bfff  libsystem_trace.dylib (72.1.3) 
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
> 0x7fff8b576000 -     0x7fff8b577ffb  libremovefile.dylib (35) <3485B5F4-6CE8-3C62-8DFD-8736ED6E8531>
> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
> 0x7fff8b578000 -     0x7fff8b57afff  libsystem_configuration.dylib (699.1.5) <5E14864E-089A-3D84-85A4-980B776427A8>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
> 0x7fff8b9b6000 -     0x7fff8b9bfff7  libsystem_notify.dylib (133.1.1) <61147800-F320-3DAA-850C-BADF33855F29>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
> 0x7fff8b9c0000 -     0x7fff8b9c2ff7  libsystem_coreservices.dylib (9) <41B7C578-5A53-31C8-A96F-C73E030B0938>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
> 0x7fff8bb26000 -     0x7fff8bb31fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60061) 
> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
> 0x7fff8c00e000 -     0x7fff8c015ff7  libcompiler_rt.dylib (35) 
> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
> 0x7fff8c020000 -     0x7fff8c096fe7  libcorecrypto.dylib (233.1.2) 
> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
> 0x7fff8db6e000 -     0x7fff8db7fff7  libsystem_coretls.dylib (35.1.2) 
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
> 0x7fff8ddcf000 -     0x7fff8ddd7ffb  libcopyfile.dylib (118.1.2) <0C68D3A6-ACDD-3EF3-991A-CC82C32AB836>
> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
> 0x7fff8e3ac000 -     0x7fff8e3d4fff  libxpc.dylib (559.10.3) <876216DC-D5D3-381E-8AF9-49AE464E5107> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
> 0x7fff8e4e7000 -     0x7fff8e4ecff7  libunwind.dylib (35.3)  /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
> 0x7fff8eb14000 -     0x7fff8eb15ff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (65) <9615D10A-FCA7-3BE4-AA1A-1B195DACE1A1>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
> 0x7fff8f358000 -     0x7fff8f35eff7  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (167.1.10)
> <29AB225B-D7FB-30ED-9600-65D44B9A9442>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
> 0x7fff8f950000 -     0x7fff8f951fff  libsystem_secinit.dylib (18) <581DAD0F-6B63-3A48-B63B-917AF799ABAA>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
> 0x7fff8fd5d000 -     0x7fff8fd95ffb  libsystem_network.dylib (411.1) <2EC3A005-473F-3C36-A665-F88B5BACC7F0>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
> 0x7fff9021b000 -     0x7fff9021bff7  libunc.dylib (29) <5676F7EA-C1DF-329F-B006-D2C3022B7D70> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
> 0x7fff92f65000 -     0x7fff92fabff7  libauto.dylib (186)  /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
> 0x7fff93271000 -     0x7fff93282ff7  libz.1.dylib (55) <88C7C7DE-04B8-316F-8B74-ACD9F3DE1AA1> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
> 0x7fff934d1000 -     0x7fff934f9fff  libsystem_info.dylib (459) 
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
> 0x7fff935da000 -     0x7fff93605fff  libc++abi.dylib (125) <88A22A0F-87C6-3002-BFBA-AC0F2808B8B9> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
> 0x7fff93612000 -     0x7fff93613fff  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent (2.0 - 25)
> <2D61A2C3-C83E-3A3F-8EC1-736DBEC250AB>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
> 0x7fff93ed4000 -     0x7fff93ed5fff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (100)
> <2EE8E436-5CDC-34C5-9959-5BA218D507FB>
> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
> 0x7fff945fa000 -     0x7fff94617fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2782.10.72) <97CD7ACD-EA0C-3434-BEFC-FCD013D6BB73>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
> 0x7fff947bd000 -     0x7fff947d9ff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (53.1.1) <19BCC257-5717-3502-A71F-95D65AFA861B>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
> 0x7fff947da000 -     0x7fff947e3fff  libsystem_pthread.dylib (105.10.1) <3103AA7F-3BAE-3673-9649-47FFD7E15C97>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
> 0x7fff9494c000 -     0x7fff94a30fff  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (52.10.1) <2A2924DE-63FB-37F6-B102-84D69240675B>
> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
> 0x7fff94b1b000 -     0x7fff94b4bfff  libsystem_m.dylib (3086.1) <1E12AB45-6D96-36D0-A226-F24D9FB0D9D6>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
> 0x7fff94e80000 -     0x7fff94e82ff7  libquarantine.dylib (76) 
> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
> 0x7fff95913000 -     0x7fff95913ff7  liblaunch.dylib (559.10.3)  /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
>
> External Modification Summary:   Calls made by other processes
> targeting this process:
> task_for_pid: 0
> thread_create: 0
> thread_set_state: 0   Calls made by this process:
> task_for_pid: 0
> thread_create: 0
> thread_set_state: 0   Calls made by all processes on this machine:
> task_for_pid: 3981
> thread_create: 0
> thread_set_state: 0
>
> VM Region Summary: ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=86.3M
> resident=14.6M(17%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=71.7M(83%) Writable
> regions: Total=63.1M written=12.5M(20%) resident=28.6M(45%)
> swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=34.5M(55%)   REGION TYPE
> VIRTUAL
> ===========                      ======= Kernel Alloc Once                     4K MALLOC                             54.3M MALLOC (admin)
> 16K STACK GUARD                           4K Stack
> 64.0M VM_ALLOCATE                          12K
> __DATA                             1308K
> __LINKEDIT                         71.7M
> __TEXT                             14.6M shared memory                         4K
> ===========                      ======= TOTAL                             206.0M

Comment: Please re-include the output in your post, but instead use `<pre>` or code blocks to preserve the whitespace. As it stands the output is very difficult to read.

Comment: When I use the <pre> tags it says code is not properly formatted with 4 space indentations.

Answer (score 0):

Well persistence (and being stubborn) payed off. After hours of searching on the errors I was getting and trying a myriad of things I found the problem.

XCODE was not installed! So no command line tools. Honestly I don't know why not. It was there before the upgrade to Yosemite. I was not able to find out if the upgrade removes it, or not. I would not think so. But I know I did not remove it myself.

Long story short (too late)...
I followed the steps at this tutorial, skipping steps I knew that were working, like git, etc...
http://installrails.com/

Now I'm back up and running. Maybe the steps taken here will help someone else in the future. Thanks for looking...
David